# CygWin: How can I know what packages need (are pending) to be upgraded?

Tags: cygwin, package-management

If I do on the **installer** directory of CygWin:

```
setup-x86.exe --root c:\CygWin --upgrade-also -q
```

I get all (or so it seems) the **packages upgraded** from the last internet repository I used successfully.
I can **get a list** of all the upgraded packages at `setup.log` in the same local packages directory.

Is there any way to get this list **before the update** to be done?

I think it could be useful to get prepared for **long downloads**. Something like the classic:

```
271 packages can be updated.
121 updates are security updates.
```

that apt-get on Ubuntu reports.